# Second order system $x''+Ax=0$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $A$ be a symmetric  n x n matrix. Consider the second-order system $x''+Ax=0.$ For which $A$ are the solutions bounded? For which $A$ are the solutions periodic? Answer the same questions if $A$ is not symmetric.

Comment: Can you define "limited"? Does that mean "bounded"?

Comment: yes,i  will correct it

Comment: And your thoughts on the subject are?

Comment: Can you answer the questions when $n=1$? Does that give you any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general operator solution to the problem
$$ \ddot{E}(t)+ A \cdot E(t) = 0, ~~~ E(0) = E_0, \dot{E}(0) = E_1$$
with $A$ symmetric is
$$E(t) = \cos(A^{1/2}t) \cdot E_0 + \sin(A^{1/2}t) \cdot A^{-1/2} E_1,$$
where $A^{1/2}$ is the symmetric squareroot of $A$.

The solution to the problem you posed follows from this by choosing $E_0$, $E_1$ and $x_0$ appropriately for your initial conditions to set $x(t) := E(t)\cdot x_0$.

This means that the solution is periodic and bounded if $A$ has only positive eigenvalues and otherwise is non-periodic and non-bounded.

The non-symmetric case can be traced back to the symmetric case by considering a polar decomposition.

Comment: Very nice trick, I appreciate it.

Comment: These are the solutions if A is semi-positive defined (the eigenvalues of A are not negative) Otherwise we must have the solutions $e^{(-A)^{1/2}t}c_0+e^{-(-A)^{1/2}t}c_1$

Comment: These are covered by my general solution, as $e^{-t} = \cos(it) + i \sin(it)$. Note that the squareroot of $A$ is purely imaginary if $A$ is negative definite.

Comment: considering the polar decomposition A=UP we can define the square root of P but not of U?